# FSharp Record Types With Entity Framework Code-First

Tags: entity-framework, f#

I am doing a proof of concept in a line of business application where I want to swap out the current C# Code-First Entity Framework implementation with a F# one.  I am following [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/04/04/f-code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4-1.aspx) article which seems to work pretty well, but I was hoping to use FSharp record types instead of the classes that the article uses.  When I try and add a data annotation to a record type like this:

```
type Family = {[<Key>]Id:int; LastName:string; IsRegistered:bool}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error   1   The type 'Key' is not defined
```

Is there a way to use data annotations with record types?  Apparently, EF Code-First needs annotations...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Record types support attributes just fine (and with the syntax you have).

Check if your reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` is in order, that's where `KeyAttribute` is defined.

**Edit**: EF wants to work with properties, that's why using a record doesn't mesh well with EF. You can still make it work in F# 3.0+ by marking the record with `CLIMutable` attribute (this generates property setters and a parameterless constructor which are taken for granted by C#-centric frameworks and libraries).

The article you're looking at was written with F# 2.0 in mind - `CLIMutable` wasn't around yet and there was no way of using records for that.

Comment: That was it.  I added a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations but I forgot to add it via #r to the top of my script file.  Thanks!

Comment: I am still running into a problem: EntityType 'Family' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.  Did I attribute it incorrectly?

Comment: Ah, that's right, I guess I know what's going on. Check the edit.